# How to Generate a QR code using PHP?

Tags: php, qr-code

I am attempting to turn some data into a QR on a webpage. To do this I am using 'php qrcode'.

Sourceforge Home Page of library: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

I am unable to generate the QR code using the library. Am I missing a PHP extension.

Thinking I was missing the GD2 extension, I did:

```
brew install gd
```

Current Code:

```
  include( '../phpqrcode/qrlib.php' );
  QRcode::png( 'PHP QR Code : )' );
```

Current Output:

�PNG  IHDRWWKK/PLTE���U��~�IDAT8��ұ � PG.�N�t�tـ,V��H,pe�����4Ĵq�k�� ��j���'^l�����p�h�Sn�8D>3T-�%�����:\��z���4{oL��!C�-����_o�r���r��m��x+��,}��ő��|i����ʚt{oZ6\,i�{�5몏{���Ϫ����/MIEND�B`�

Edit: 
I have tried changing the html header to image/png. Same results.

```
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="image/png" charset="UTF-8">
```

Edit: Full Sample Code, Same results, no QR code.

```
<?php header('Content-type: image/png'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="image/png" charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

include( '../phpqrcode/qrlib.php' );
QRcode::png( 'PHP QR Code : )' );

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: The following shows same results

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');

include( '../phpqrcode/qrlib.php' );
QRcode::png( 'PHP QR Code : )' );
?>
```

Edit:
Using laravel framework

Comment: you have to set the content-type header so the browser knows it's an image, not text

Comment: Try adding `header('Content-type: image/png');` to the top of your file!

Comment: Try (1) putting this code as **test.php** `(<?php include( '../phpqrcode/qrlib.php' );QRcode::png( 'PHP QR Code : )' );?>` , then (2) put <img src='test.php'> in your laravel view.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');

include( '../phpqrcode/qrlib.php' );
QRcode::png( 'PHP QR Code : )' );
?>
```

When outputting an image, you don't need HTML tags. Alternatively, you could use `img` tag with `data:...` source. For an example, see [here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

Answer (score -3):

You can use the phpqrcode library for use, please visit [this page](https://codingrakitan.blogspot.com/2019/07/cara-membuat-qrcode-mengunakan-phpqrcode.html)

Comment: OP says he's already using that library. I think he needs more detailed help on how to generate the QR code.